# How can I prevent the player's car from go through road accelerators in the reverse direction?

Tags: trackmania-forever

When creating a track in Trackmania Nations Forever, is it possible to prevent the player's car to go through road accelerators in reverse direction?

Ex: When I put 2 road accelerators serially:

[image]

The player's car can easily go through road accelerators in reverse direction as demonstrated in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Em3am64t8LM).

Comment: Not sure if you've noticed or not, but the video is set to private.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there's no way to prevent players doing this.

You should consider why it's a bad thing to have the player be able to go backwards here, given that unless the player is incredibly skilled (ie. likely to win anyway) they're not going to be able to consistently land this method, and that it's quite slow to execute.

If your intention is to prevent players using it to take a shortcut, then you may want to consider additional checkpointing to close that loophole instead. Alternatively, you could use a jump or ramp to prevent travel in the reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MediaTracker to try to detect it and force the camera to go wonky, or put a huge message or an overlay on the screen.

But I'm against that. Let the player have complete freedom, it is a lot more fun this way! Let the player go backwards if he/she wants!